# Oil overfill repair

Tags: engine, oil-change, chrysler

At 14,561 miles, my Chrysler van was due for an oil change.  The dealer put in 12 quarts instead of the specified 6 quarts.  Oil smoke came out of the exhaust and the engine ran very rough for 20 miles.  The dealer drained out 6 quarts and said everything is OK.  What more should be done?  Compression test?  I'm concerned that I will have problems in the future such as valve seal or main seal failure caused by this error.

Comment: Someone else will likely chime in with advice on what to expect from such an overfill, but as a dude who's been doing oil changes for years, my advice to you right now is if they overfill your engine by THAT much, don't ever go back there. Your oil change was likely performed by a monkey on drugs.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have documentation of what happened!  You may well have damaged your engine.  The issue is that if there is too much oil in the engine, the crankshaft spins in the oil like a mixer in your kitchen.  This works air into the oil and turns it into foam.  In this worst case the oil pump cannot move that foam and the engine will actually seize like there was no oil at all.

Since you did not get all the way to a failure, you are in that unfortunate case where you may have some extra wear, but nothing obvious is broken.  If you still have a sample of the original oil you could send it in for analysis and see how much metal there is in it.  If the levels are normal you are fine, if they are high you might be in trouble.

Good Luck!